# Save image/video file to app's internal storage in subfolder

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

I know similar questions like that have been asked a lot here already but I just can't find an answer that works for me.

I have a File object which has a path pointing to the SD card (external storage). For example:

```
 File selectedFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20160725-185624.png");
```

What I want to do now is to save that image/video to a subfolder of my app's internal storage.

For example, saving the File to here:
INTERNAL_STORAGE/20/public_gallery/300.png

The problem I have is when I'm using

```
outputStream = context.openFileOutput("20/public_gallery/300.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
...
outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
...
```

I can't use any "/" for a subfolder.

If anyone could provide me a small code example I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Just use absolute path and FileOutputStream.

Comment: `SD card (external storage)`. No. A micro SD card is removable storage.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/......`. That is external storage. Has nothing to do with a micro SD card.

Comment: `INTERNAL_STORAGE/20/public_gallery/` ?? A public gallery in internal storage? Strange. Please explain.

Comment: I will have "public_gallery" and "private_gallery" subfolders in the internal storage. This is just a name that happens to contain "public" in it. It's not the actual external storage.

Comment: with "SD card" I mean the external/public/SD storage of the phone that is accessible for all apps and which is not only accessible for my own application. in the example above the user selects a photo from the "Screenshot" folder. What I want to do is to save a copy of that selected file to the app's internal storage to the subfolder I mentioned above (the one with "public_gallery") in the path name.

Comment: getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/20/public_gallery/300.png". And use FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/your_app_folder" + "/any_subfolder/" + "filename.extension"
file = new File(destFilePath);
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
  out = new FileOutputStream(file);
  ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(out!=null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

"/" shouldn't be a problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in a project in the office.

Here is a fully working example on how to save a file to the internal storage that the user has selected with a file browser dialog:

```
public boolean copyFileToPrivateStorage(File originalFileSelectedByTheUser, Contact contact) {

    File storeInternal = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/76/public"); // "/data/user/0/net.myapp/files/76/public"
    if (!storeInternal.exists()) {
        storeInternal.mkdirs();
    }
    File dstFile = new File(storeInternal, "1.png"); // "/data/user/0/net.myapp/files/76/public/1.png"

    try {
        if (originalFileSelectedByTheUser.exists()) {
            // Now we copy the data of the selected file to the file created in the internal storage
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(originalFileSelectedByTheUser);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = is.read(buff)) > 0) {
                os.write(buff, 0, len);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();

            return true;
        } else {
            String error = "originalFileSelectedByTheUser does not exist";
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

It takes the File "originalFileSelectedByTheUser" that is somewhere on the external storage such as the Screenshots directory and saves a copy of it to the location in "dstFile" in the internal storage so only the app can access the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is also Working in **Android Version 13+**

Firstly you have to declare **Internet Permission** to Download Video from internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
val dexOutputDir: File = codeCacheDir
val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
dexOutputDir.setReadOnly()
myExternalFile = File(
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
    "/$filepath/"
)
if (!myExternalFile!!.exists()) {
    myExternalFile!!.mkdirs()
}
fileWaterMark = File(myExternalFile, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".mp4")
btnDownload.setOnClickListener {
 downloadVideo(url, fileWaterMark)
}
```

}

```
private fun downloadVideo(url: String?, outputFile: File?) {
try {
    val u = URL(url)
    val conn = u.openConnection()
    val contentLength = conn.contentLength
    val stream = DataInputStream(u.openStream())
    val buffer = ByteArray(contentLength)
    stream.readFully(buffer)
    stream.close()
    val fos = DataOutputStream(FileOutputStream(outputFile))
    fos.write(buffer)
    fos.flush()
    fos.close()
    openVideo()
} catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
    println("!!!e.getMessage()FileNotFound = " + e.message)
    return  // swallow a 404
} catch (e: IOException) {
    println("!!!e.getMessage()IOException = " + e.message)
    return  // swallow a 404
}
}
```

Below Code for **share or preview Downloaded** Video

```
    private fun openVideo() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("YourPath"))
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("YourPath"), "video/mp4")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```